# Flutter audiowave_form package can't access audio file

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show the audio waves from the audiowave_forms package on flutter, but the package throws a paltform excpetion.
the message of the exception reads : Failed to open file 'path to audio file.mp3'. (No such file or directory)
heres the code:

```
AudioFileWaveforms(
                    size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 100.0),
                    playerController: viewModel.controller,
                    enableSeekGesture: false,
                    waveformType: WaveformType.long,
                    waveformData: viewModel.waves,
                    playerWaveStyle: const PlayerWaveStyle(
                      fixedWaveColor: Colors.white54,
                      liveWaveColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      spacing: 8,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Function call in the view:

```
 @override
  void onViewModelReady(CallViewModel viewModel) async {
    await viewModel.getWavesfromData();
  }
```

And here's the code from the view model for initiating the controller and getting the waves from the audiofile:

```
PlayerController _controller = PlayerController();
  PlayerController get controller => _controller; // Initialise

  List<double> _waves = [];
  List<double> get waves => _waves;

  Future<void> getWavesfromData() async {
    _waves = await _controller //<--------- here's where the exception is thrown
        .extractWaveformData(
          path: 'audio/Recording3.mp3',
          noOfSamples: 100,
        )
        .catchError((e) => print("print $e"));
    rebuildUi();
  }
```

here's the path in pubspec.yaml:
[adding the audio folder where the file is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opdwb.jpg)

I checked the indents in pubspec.yaml and path name and they're good, the controller is supposed to extract the waves from the file in the path provided and pass it in the view.

Comment: can you add your pubspec file also?

Comment: Is `path: 'audio/Recording3.mp3',` part of your assets?

Comment: I added an image showing the pubspec.yaml part where the code is, in the assets, I added 'audio/'